# How to make bootstrap grid more flud?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way to make bootstrap grid more fluid in showing information.

this is the code I am using now.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row design">
          <div class="col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp">
            <img src="assets/images/projects/traverse/01.jpg" class="imgs">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

but after having like 5-10 of these, the result is something like this.

[image]

how can I fill that empty spot in there? the pics I am uploading are not of the same parameters.
[image]

or when it is an empty spot, how to add make the grid more responsive and fill the empty parts in there?

I am using only css and html, but don't mind javascript or something else as long as it gets the ob done

Comment: Can you share link ?

Comment: @vadivela for what exactly?

Comment: can you share kind of fiddle or full html code, just a block of code and images will not help